# How to properly login to Google Play Games services in Unity?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, google-play-games

I'm just looking for some help from someone who has expert nce working with Google Play Games Services in Unity on Android. Basically, I've got my project all set up in the Google Developer console, and using the most recent version of the Google-made plugin for Unity.

I've got my package signinf, and onstart in my game I call

```
Social.localUser.Authenticate((bool success) => {
    return;
});
```

To simply attempt a login. It appears to work but there are a few things. First, it seems to work on any account, rather than only those I've added in the developer console as testers (I'm using the debug key, currently.)

Second, it doesn't show up in my recent games in the Play Games app.

Third, it pops up with a loading screen and then seems to login every time I launch the app, I thought this would only happen once (although it never did come up with a thing asking me to sign in, just a loading screen, I figured I had just set it previously on other games to always sign right in.

And fourth, it doesn't pop-up with my Play Games level and score, like it does on other games I've downloaded from the Play Store and play, when I Start them.

Is this normal? If no, any ideas? I can provide screenshots if needed!

Comment: try the offical documentation of google code lab on this link https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/playservices_unity/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0

Comment: Thanks. Every time I Googled anything to do with Google Play Games Services and Unity, it came back up with the github repo. That repo has a guide, but it's not nearly as comprehensive as this.